# Python exif how to use GPSInfo

Tags: python, exif

I am trying to get the latitude direction of an image (North or South). Can you help me with the correct syntax for GPSInfo?

```
from PIL import Image
def image(filename)
 try:
    inputfile = Image.open(file)
 except:
    print('File cannot be found')

 latitude_direction = inputfile._getexif()['GPSInfo'][1]
 print(latitude_direction)
```

Answer (score 0):

The dict returned by `_getexif()` is indexed by the tag id, not some string name.  In this case the *GPSInfo* tag id is `8825` in hex (`34853` in decimal). See the end of table 17 in section 4.6.8 of the [EXIF spec](http://www.cipa.jp/std/documents/e/DC-008-Translation-2016-E.pdf).  However, the GPSInfo tag is dict of GPS tags indexed also by tag id.  In table 15 in section 4.6.6, we see that the latitude direction (named `GPSLatitudeRef`) has an id of `1`, which your code had correct.

So you should get what you want by using the following line:

```
latitude_direction = inputfile._getexif()[0x8825][1]
```